React Native Throttle Control: Handle Jumps on Initial Touch, Seeking Smooth Dragging Without Teleportation
I'm building a throttle control using React Native. The issue is when I initially touch the throttle handle, it teleports to a different position rather than staying at the point of contact and dragging smoothly. I'm trying to achieve a realistic, friction-based throttle movement, but the handle jumps to the bottom/top upon the first touch. I need the handle to start from where it is touched and drag smoothly without teleporting.
Here is a video of the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbu0dQUEhGo
Also here is my Throttle.js file :-
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, PanResponder, Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ThrottleLever = ({ onMove }) => {
  const [throttle, setThrottle] = useState(0.5); // Initialize throttle at midpoint (0.5)
  const panY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current; // Track Y-axis

  const THRESHOLD = 10; // Minimum pixels to move before reacting
  const SENSITIVITY = 0.5; // Scale factor to reduce sensitivity

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
        // Ignore small movements
        if (Math.abs(gestureState.dy) < THRESHOLD) return;

        // Scale the Y movement
        let scaledY = gestureState.dy * SENSITIVITY;
        let newY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, scaledY));

        // Convert Y-axis value from -100 to 100 range to 0 to 1 range
        let mappedY = (newY + 100) / 200;

        panY.setValue(newY); // Set Y-axis value (for UI movement)
        setThrottle(mappedY); // Update the throttle (0 to 1)
        onMove(mappedY); // Send the 0 to 1 value to the parent
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
        // On release, apply friction-like effect
        let finalY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, gestureState.dy * SENSITIVITY));
        let finalMappedY = (finalY + 100) / 200; // Map -100 to 1

        setThrottle(finalMappedY);
        onMove(finalMappedY); // Send final 0 to 1 value to parent

        // Apply a friction-like animation to smoothly settle the lever
        Animated.spring(panY, {
          toValue: finalY, // Final position
          friction: 2,    // Higher friction for a slower response
          tension: 20,     // Lower tension for a softer spring
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      }
    })
  ).current;

  return (
    <View style={styles.leverBase}>
      <Animated.View
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[
          styles.leverHandle,
          { transform: [{ translateY: panY }] } // Only Y-axis movement
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  leverBase: {
    width: 60,
    height: 250,
    backgroundColor: '#888',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden', // Prevent lever handle from moving outside the base
  },
  leverHandle: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});

export default ThrottleLever;


I implemented a throttle lever using PanResponder in React Native, and it works smoothly when dragging. However, when I touch the handle, it teleports to the top or bottom before I even drag it. Since this is meant to simulate an aircraft throttle lever, this teleportation can cause serious fluctuations in throttle control, making it unusable for realistic applications. I need help making the handle follow the touch point smoothly without jumping when pressed.
